# Find the height and the velocity of the object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity, projectile

A bolt is detached from the lower part of an elevator cabin that is ascending with velocity 6meters/second and for 3 seconds comes to the point from where the elevator started to ascend. Find:
in which height is the end of the elevator in the moment when from it the bolt was detached. What is the velocity of the bolt when it comes to the point the elevator started to ascend.

Here's what i did:h=v0t+(gt^2)/2 vo is the first velocity
h=18+(10*9)/2=63
v^2-v0^2=2gs
v^2=2gs+vo^2=2*10*63+36 v=36
But my teacher told me that I did it wrong, because the bolt firstly goes up (maybe after it is detached from the elevator) and then goes down. Could you correct my mistake?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of problem can be simplified if you use the frame of reference of the elevator.  Now the bolt falls from rest, chasing the "starting point" which starts a distance $h$ below and moves down at a constant $6 $ m/s.  The bolt catches up in $3$ seconds.

Same problem, but the equations are simpler...